# Microsoft Graph API search function doesn't work as expected

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to do a basic search for displayName of my organization using the Microsoft Graph API.

The problem is, the search function doesn't work as expected. Based on my tests the search function doesn't actually do fuzzy searching properly, the logic is obviously based on startsWith and endsWith and not contains. For my needs this doesn't suffice because my organization's displayName contains both Korean name and English name. For example :

A user with displayName : 이선빈(Annie Lee)

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$search="displayName:이선"](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$search=%22displayName:%EC%9D%B4%EC%84%A0%22) returns the correct result.
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$search="displayName:Annie"](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$search=%22displayName:Annie%22) returns no result.
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$search="displayName:Lee"](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$search=%22displayName:Lee%22) returns no result
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$search="displayName:Lee](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$search=%22displayName:Lee))" returns the correct result

What was the point of updating the API with the search function if actual fuzzy searching wasn't supported? $filter using startsWith and endsWith operator has been supported since the beginning, but the reason why people wanted the $search function was to be able to actually query for displayName properly using a contains function. It seems Microsoft essentially "added" a search function when functionally it's basically the $filter with startsWith and endsWith query.

Am I missing something with the API? Is there a possible workaround in my case?

Comment: At first I thought you missed adding request header `ConsistencyLevel:eventual`, but I found I faced the same issue as you described. Then I found [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-query-parameter#using-search-on-directory-object-collections) and this may tell the reason.

Comment: @TinyWang
"Currently, tokenization only works when the casing is changing from lowercase to uppercase, so HELLOworld is considered a single token: helloworld, and HelloWORld is two tokens: hello, world." So since Korean doesn't have uppercase, and paranthesis isn't considered a delimiter in the tokenization, search on "Lee", "Annie" fails because graph considers the entire displayname one token. Wow. Honestly this implementation makes zero sense considering the fact that displayName has a character limit. Why can't they just implement string.contains?

Comment: I also puzzled with it as [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-7-use-search-to-get-users-with-display-names-that-contain-the-letters-wa-or-the-letters-to-including-a-count-of-returned-objects) described the `$search` method as "contains"...

Comment: I'm the PM for the Advanced Query Parameters. $search tokenization considers the parenthesis character `(` as a token delimiter, so 이선빈(Annie Lee) is split into these tokens: `이선빈`, `(`, `Annie`, `Lee`, `)`.
It is very weird that your queries searching for "Annie" or "Lee" do not return any result. We tried on our end, and we cannot reproduce this. Can you share the request-id for your failed search to help us debugging this issue?

**Note**: we cannot implement a "true" contains algorithm due to performance reasons, we believe that tokenization search is the best compromise.

Comment: @LucaSpolidoroMSFT You are correct, my test cases (and the original question) were wrong in that many of the users I searched for didn't have a space between the first and last English name. It still doesn't solve the issue that Korean names start with surname and then end with given name, so for 이선빈 it's surname 이 (Lee) and 선빈 (Sunbin). I need the query for a chatbot, and most Koreans would ask for 선빈. Languages with complex characters like Chinese, Japanese, Korean should have different tokenization behavior IMO. Or, a $search function for givenName would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the clarification in your last comment.
You can solve the issue by taking advantage of `$search` behavior for non-tokenized properties: it will default to `startsWith` operator.

Your final query should look like this:
`/users?$search="displayName:<INPUT>" OR "givenName:<INPUT>" OR "surname:<INPUT>"`

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The search implementation does not support "contains" logic. Instead, it uses a tokenization approach that works by extracting words from the property value and the search string using spaces, numbers, different casing, and symbols as shown in the following examples:
Different casing: HelloWorld or helloWORLD => hello, world

try to lowercasing $search term 'Annie'=>'annie' or 'Lee'=>'lee'